# ASP.NET WebApi - HttpClient - Method not found

Tags: asp.net, httpclient, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to use Asp.NET WebAPI module but I get a weird error.
When I try to run this simple program:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        System.Net.Http.HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        string data = client.GetStringAsync("http://www.kralizek.se/").Result;

        Console.WriteLine(data);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

I have this error.

```
System.MissingMethodException was unhandled
  Message=Method not found: 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<System.String> System.Net.Http.HttpClient.GetStringAsync(System.String)'.
  Source=Connector.App
  StackTrace:
       at ConnectorApp.Program.Main(String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

The error occurs in Visual Studio and in LinqPad but it doesn't occur to my colleague.

I thought there could have been some kind of conflict with .NET 4.5 dev preview so I uninstalled it but without any benefit.

Thanks

Comment: are you referencing .net 4.5?

Comment: no i'm not. but the same bin folder runs "as is" on my colleague workstation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ASP.NET Web API Beta is explicitly not compatible with the .NET Framework 4.5 Developer Preview.  See http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/mvc4-release-notes#_Toc303253802.

I would recommend uninstalling both and reinstalling the Web API after cleaning out both.  I don't think uninstalling .NET 4.5 *after* installing Web API will do the trick.

Comment: This is partly correct:
I uninstalled Visual Studio 11 DP and .NET 4.5. After that I repaired VS2010 and everything was working.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use pre-RTM WebAPI after you have installed VS2012. Add the following to your app/web.config

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30AD4FE6B2A6AEED" culture="neutral"/>
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.5.0.0" newVersion="4.5.0.0"/>
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0 - 2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0"/>
        </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

The problem is that the RTM version of System.Net.Http overrides the pre-RTM version because the newer version is in the GAC and the assy discovery prefers the newer version. Even if you *explicity* file reference the older version (grrr).

The NewtonSoft entry isn't strictly necessary...

Anyway this has worked for us.